# Angle between vectors by using cross product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

Given $A=(0,10,2)$ and $B=(0,-4,0.5)$, find the angle between $A$ and $B$ using the cross product.

My attempt by using dot product:

$$\cos (\theta)=\frac{A\cdot B}{|A||B|}=\frac{(0)(0)+10(-4)+2(0.5)}{\sqrt{0^2+10^2+2^2}\sqrt{0^2+(-4)^2+(0.5)^2}}=\frac{-39}{41.1}$$

Then $\theta=\arccos(-0.948)= 161.44$

Now using the cross product:

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{|A\times B|}{|A||B|}=\frac{ \begin{vmatrix}
    i & j & k \\
    0 & 10 & 2 \\
    0 & -4 & 0.5 \\
    \end{vmatrix}}{\sqrt{0^2+10^2+2^2} \sqrt{0^2+(-4)^2+(0.5)^2}}=
\frac{|10(0.5)i+0(-4)k+0(2)j-0(10)k-2(-4)i-(0.5)(0)j|}{\sqrt{1690}}=\frac{|13i|}{41.1}=\frac{13}{41.1}=0.316$$

but then I get $\theta=\arcsin(0.316)=18.42$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: radians or degrees? @Or18

Comment: @Yassir degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your two angles add to $180^\circ$.  The $\arcsin$ function is defined to have a limited range so it is a function, but you need to select the correct angle of all the ones that have the sine you calculate.  As the vectors are almost in opposite directions the correct answer is the one you got from the dot product.

Answer (score 1):

The cross product isn’t a conclusive means to determine the angle $\theta$ between two vectors, since within $\theta$’s range $[0,180^\circ],$ $$\sin\theta=x\implies\\\theta=\arcsin x\text{ or }180^\circ-\arcsin x.$$

(On the other hand, for $\theta\in[0,180^\circ],$ $$\cos\theta=x\implies\theta=\arccos x.)$$